# Jedi popup window: how to make it larger than its parent frame

Tags: auto-complete-mode, popup

I am using jedi and auto-complete to provide some help during my Python coding session. As advertised in the [jedi's website](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/), completion and documentation are shown correctly as:

[image: Popup window with a large frame]

However, when the frame is barely larger than the function's name and basic info (the first popup, in gray), then the documentation popup (the second one, in yellow) is crammed so it's not larger than the frame that contained the code. For example:

[image: Popup window with a smaller frame]

This behavior also happens when you have several nested scopes in your code and your function is near the left border of the frame.

Is it possible for the popup to be bigger than the containing frame? Does anyone know another solution for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to do some looking around for you on the [github popup.el issues](https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el/issues). What I found was [this post](https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el/issues/21) which seems to say that if there is a scroll bar the window won't go over it.

There also seems to be a `max-width` variable which you can set to limit how large the grey portion of the popup is. That is talked about in [this pull request](https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el/pull/29).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the input.... it seems that there is no solution for my problem. Setting the max-width will apparently change the grey portion, but the yellow portion will still show the problem.

Comment: @YuppieNetworking I was hoping that it would be possible to make it really small, sorry. Did you open an issue on their github? I assume there might already be one open though